# C# Switch expressions returning different result

Tags: c#

I've switched to C# 8 on one of my projects. And I've been moving all of my `switch` statements to expressions. However I found out that my project started working differently and I've found out that it was because of the `switch` expression. Lets get this code for example

```
class Program
{
    public enum DataType
    {
        Single,
        Double,
        UInt16,
        UInt32,
        UInt64,
        Int16,
        Int32,
        Int64,
        Byte
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        dynamic value1 = 5;
        dynamic value2 = 6;

        var casted = CastToType(value1, DataType.Int16);
        var casted1 = CastToTypeExpression(value2, DataType.Int16);


        var type = casted.GetType(); // Int16
        var type1 = casted1.GetType(); // Double
        var bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(casted); // byte arr with 2 el => [5, 0] <- expected behavior 
        var bytes1 = BitConverter.GetBytes(casted1); // byte arr with 8 el => [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 24, 64]
    }

    public static dynamic CastToType(dynamic value, DataType type)
    {
        switch (type)
        {
            case DataType.Byte:
                return (byte)value;
            case DataType.Double:
                return (double)value;
            case DataType.Int16:
                return (short)value;
            case DataType.Int32:
                return (int)value;
            case DataType.Int64:
                return (long)value;
            case DataType.Single:
                return (float)value;
            case DataType.UInt16:
                return (ushort)value;
            case DataType.UInt32:
                return (uint)value;
            case DataType.UInt64:
                return (ulong)value;
            default: throw new InvalidCastException();
        }
    }

    public static dynamic CastToTypeExpression(dynamic value, DataType type)
    {
        return type switch
        {
            DataType.Byte => (byte)value,
            DataType.Double => (double)value,
            DataType.Int16 => (short)value,
            DataType.Int32 => (int)value,
            DataType.Int64 => (long)value,
            DataType.Single => (float)value,
            DataType.UInt16 => (ushort)value,
            DataType.UInt32 => (uint)value,
            DataType.UInt64 => (ulong)value,
            _ => throw new InvalidCastException(),
        };
    }
}
```

I've wrote the result as a comment, but tl;dr when classic switch is used casting the value returns the value in the expected Type, but when switch expression is used it returns type of "Double", resulting to different `byte[]` when getting the bytes of the value.

What's the difference between the two? What do I miss?

Comment: I can't exactly explain why and how this happens but if you have a look at a decompiled version of your code at here (https://gist.github.com/MaDOS/4904683d461d022e4b24f4080009ae5e) you notice that the compiler seems to notice that all possible returning types of the expression will fit into a double and automatically declares a double where it will store whatever result will be returned. (https://gist.github.com/MaDOS/4904683d461d022e4b24f4080009ae5e#file-swith-vs-expression-decompiled-cs-L217)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In your switch *statement* form, each arm is returning a value directly. It's converting from the numeric type directly to `object`, as that's effectively the return type of the method.

Your switch *expression* form is slightly different. It first extracts a result from the switch expression, then converts that result to the declared return type. So what's the type of the switch expression? It's the "best" type from all of the types of the individual expressions in the arms of the switch expression.

All of those types can be implicitly converted to `double` (which is one of the types itself), so that's the best type. So your switch expression method is equivalent to:

```cs
public static dynamic CastToTypeExpression(dynamic value, DataType type)
{
    double result = type switch
    {
        DataType.Byte => (byte)value,
        DataType.Double => (double)value,
        DataType.Int16 => (short)value,
        DataType.Int32 => (int)value,
        DataType.Int64 => (long)value,
        DataType.Single => (float)value,
        DataType.UInt16 => (ushort)value,
        DataType.UInt32 => (uint)value,
        DataType.UInt64 => (ulong)value,
        _ => throw new InvalidCastException(),
    };
    return result;
}
```

You can see this "best type" without using a switch expression, using implicitly typed arrays:

```
var array = new[]
{
    (byte) 0, 0.0, (short) 0, 0,
    0L, 0f, (ushort) 0, 0U, 0UL
};
```

Here the type of `array` is inferred to be `double[]`.